# probability question: find min{a,b,c}

Tags: probability

X, Y, Z: discrete random variables
Probability of X, Y, Z have distinct values is 1.
Let $a=P(X>Y), b=P(Y>z), c=P(Z>X)$

(i) Find min{a,b,c}.
   (Note: in an election, it's possible for more than half of the voters to prefer candidate A to candidate B, more than half B to C, and more than half C to A)

(ii) if X,Y,Z are i.i.d, a=b=c=1/2

Could anyone give me a clue for how to start with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: For (ii) use symmetry, i.e. $P(X>Y)=P(Y>X)$ and $P(X>Y)+P(Y>X)+P(Y=X)=1$.

Comment: For (i) it is clearly zero if you always have $X \lt Y \lt Z$.

Comment: A better question exposing the paradox would be finding $\min{a+b+c}$ and $\max{a+b+c}$.  As you would expect, $\frac32$ lies between these.

Comment: @vadim123, thanks for your help. by symmetry, wouldn't it be a=b=c=1/3?

Comment: If you look at my equation, you get $a=1/2$.  The symmetry in this case is $P(X>Y)=P(Y>X)$, because they are independent identically distributed.  It doesn't mean "any two or three things that are similar must be equal".

Comment: @Henry, thanks!! but I still not following....:(

Comment: @vadim123, oh!! Is that it is assumed the the probability of X, Y, Z have the same value equals 1, therefore, P(Y=X)=0, and a=1/2 in your equation? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any equality has probability $0$, we only have to look at six possibilities

- $p_1 = P(X \gt Y \gt Z)$
- $p_2 = P(X \gt Z \gt Y)$
- $p_3 = P(Y \gt Z \gt X)$
- $p_4 = P(Y \gt X \gt Z)$
- $p_5 = P(Z \gt X \gt Y)$
- $p_6 = P(Z \gt Y \gt X)$

and we have $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4+p_5+p_6=1$ with

- $a=p_1+p_2+p_5$;
- $b= p_3+p_4+p_1$;
- $c=p_5+p_6+p_3$.

$a,b,c$ are each sums of probabilities and so must be non-negative.

(i) If the six probabilities can take any values then

- for example it is possible $a=0$, one possibility being that $p_4=1$ and the others zero, in which case $\min \{a,b,c\}\ge 0$.
- $a+b+c =p_1+p_2 +p_5+ p_3+p_4+ p_1+p_5+p_6+p_3 = 1 + p_1+p_3+p_5$, which must lie in the range $[1,2]$, so $\min \{a,b,c\}\le \frac23$ which would for example happen if  $p_1=p_3=p_5=\frac13$ and $p_2=p_4=p_6=0$.

(ii) If $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d. then $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4=p_5=p_6 = \frac16$, so $a=b=c=\frac12$.

Comment: thanks so much!!! could I have one more question? how to get from $1 \le a+b+c \le 2$ to min{a,b,c} $\le$2/3? is there a theory for having this conclusion? thanks a lot!!")

Comment: @Lily if they all are larger than $\frac{2}{3}$, then their sum is larger than $2$.

Comment: @ftfish, yes, I understand that if min{a,b,c}>2/3, a+b+c will be larger than 2. But the trouble I'm having is the other direction of that statement,  from 1≤a+b+c≤2 to min{a,b,c}. Is it a rule or like common sense that min{a,b,c} will be the avarage of the upper bound? thank you :)

Comment: @Lily I just gave you a proof by contradiction: assume all numbers are larger than $\frac{2}{3}$, we get the result that their sum would be over $2$, which contradicts the given condition that $a+b+c\le 2$. That means the assumption was false, proving the statement.