# probability question: find sup min{a,b,c}

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

X, Y, Z: discrete random variables
Probability of X, Y, Z have distinct values is 1.

Let

$a=P(X>Y)$
$b=P(Y>Z)$
$c=P(Z>X)$

(i) Find min{a,b,c}.
(Note: in an election, it's possible for more than half of the voters to prefer candidate A to candidate B, more than half B to C, and more than half C to A)

(ii) if X,Y,Z are i.i.d, a=b=c=1/2

Parts (a) and (b) of this problem are answered here:

[probability question: find min{a,b,c}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540367/probability-question-find-mina-b-c)

(c) find min{a, b, c} and $sup_p$ min{a, b, c} when p(x = 0) = 1, and y, z are independent with p(z = 1) = p(y = −1) = p, p(z = −2) = p(y = 2) = 1 - p. $Sup_p$ denotes the supremum as p varies over [0,1].

My attempt as per the answer above:

- $p_1 = P(X \gt Y \gt Z)$
- $p_2 = P(X \gt Z \gt Y)$
- $p_3 = P(Y \gt Z \gt X)$
- $p_4 = P(Y \gt X \gt Z)$
- $p_5 = P(Z \gt X \gt Y)$
- $p_6 = P(Z \gt Y \gt X)$

with prob p: $Z=1, X=0, Y=-1 $
for $a=P(X>Y)$ holds
for $b=P(Y>Z)$ does not hold
for $c=P(Z>X)$ holds

with prob 1-p: $Y=2, X=0, Z=-2 $
for $a=P(X>Y)$ does not hold
for $b=P(Y>Z)$ holds
for $c=P(Z>X)$ does not hold

The answers are $c=a=p$ and $b = 1 - p^2$
$sup$ $min\{p, 1-p^2\}=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt5-1)$

Can someone please tell me how to get to these answers.

The first part of the answer c=a=p seems to be when $Z=1, X=0, Y=-1$ a and c are 1 which is then multiplied by p, is this correct?

How do you get $b=1-p^2$?